# What is the alternative for innodb_track_changed_pages in Debian 10/MariaDB 10.3

Tags: mariadb, innodb, percona, xtrabackup, xtradb

So we have been using Debian 9 with MariaDB 10.1. For faster backups (total DB size across three DBs is > 1TB) we have enabled `innodb_track_changed_pages`. However, that feature has gone away on MariaDB 10.3 because they changed (back) from XtraDB to InnoDB.

What is the alternative? Does MariaDB 10.3 offer anything similar? Is it not needed anymore because there is some other optimization?

Or is it best to switch to Percona Server for MySQL to keep using that feature, and would that "cross-grade" work seamlessly?